# Android: Syntax error on token ";" for Imageview

Tags: android, syntax, token

[image]

I am new to android:

I am facing an error:

```
//image view for larger display private 
    private ImageView picView;
```

**Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token**

All other variables are working perfectly except for this  one.
Any idea whats going on here ?

**UPDATE**: *Even if I comment the code ,the same error comes on the last variable declared.
But this comes only for non-primitive type and not for primitive types.*

Comment: can you please post your whole code and log cat?

Comment: Paste some of your Code here. Atleast the method or class containing this declaration.

Comment: @David: See image above.

Comment: Try after removing the line "@SuppressWarnings("depreciation")

Comment: bedi bhai } miss ho rha hai kahin.. dhyan se dekho yar !

Answer (score 0):

Check your brackets and make sure neighboring terms are correct.